# What is the form of the verb that follows "of"?

Tags: gerunds, prepositional-phrases

I wonder what is the correct form of the verb that follows  **of** 
for example, what is the correct form?

> the way of conveying

OR

> the way of convey

Comment: The correct form is "the way of **conveying**".  In general, I think we use the *present participle* after *of*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepositions take a noun phrase or gerund complement. So the right choice is

> The way of convey**ing**.